# For each get a value with a variable key

Tags: php, arrays

I find it hard to explain but my page has a multidimensional  array with all the users and I need to get values from the inner arrays without knowing the main key.

I'm not as experienced with arrays yet and I'm completely stuck right now. The function I use has 2 parameters. The first one is the input id of the user and the second is the array of the complete user list.

```
function userInfo($i, $users){
    foreach($users['data'] as $user){
        if($i = $user['id']){
            return $user['SOMENAME?']['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a example of the array I'm working with:

```
{
   "data": {
      "Doe": {
         "id": 266,
         "title": "Doe title",
         "name": "Doe",
         "key": "Some key"
      },
      "John": {
         "id": 412,
         "title": "John title",
         "name": "John",
         "key": "Some key"
      }
}
```

The function I have now simply returns Doe (The first value in the array) no matter how much arrays are in there.

How do I return the title or any of the other values when I don't know the name of the main key for that specific array?

Comment: Where does `$champion` come from? It isn't in scope for the function

Comment: @MarkBaker I changed the namespace to something more read-able but didn't double check it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your if statement, where you are assigning a value, not ccomparing it (= vs == or ===).

For the purpose of your function, I don't think you need to know the key, because you're already in the array. eg.

```
 function championInfo($i, $users){
     foreach($users['data'] as $index => $user){
        if($i == $user['id']){
            return $user['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($users['data'] as $key => $user){
    if($i = $user['id']){
        return $champion[$key]['name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($collecion as $key => $val){
```

That should get your results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "ID: {$value['id']}, Title: {$value['title']}, Name: {$value['name']}, Key: {$value['key']}<br />";
}
```

another version (if you think this is more readable)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($id, $title, $name, $key) = array_values($value);
    echo "ID: {$id}, Title: {$title}, Name: {$name}, Key: {$key}<br />";
}
```